# hardwood flooring in two rooms not parallel

Tags: flooring, hardwood

I have hardwood flooring in my dining room and another room, with kitchen in between. I want to extend the flooring to make the kitchen hardwood as well. The problem is that the flooring in the two existing rooms are not exactly parallel. They differ by a few degrees. I could run the new flooring exactly parallel to the dining room, then when it hits the door of the second room it would have an angle. Or I could try to "warp' the installation so the hardwood changes angle a little as it crosses the kitchen. Any advice?

Comment: Are there doorways here?  Just having some kind of threshold would resolve this.

Comment: Could you add a photo ?

Answer (score 1):

Just taper a couple of pieces of flooring to distribute the adjustment across a wider area.  Preferably this would be done in a doorway, as IronEagle notes.  Trim them on the female side of a tongue/grooved board, because...:

I learned this lesson the hard way:  It's worth getting a bit or blade (router?  dado?) that you can use to reconstruct the groove on the trimmed side, so your boards still fit tightly together.

Comment: I’d caution you on manipulating the size and/or angle of the boards if you can see from one room to another. If you (or a guest) can sit back and see the boards twisting and not aligning across rooms, it’ll drive you nuts in the future. (It’ll be all you look at in the future.)

Comment: Agree, Lee Sam, but we are trying to make the best of an imperfect situation, right?  The other alternative is to make sure all lines stay parallel, which would put them out of square in the kitchen and not parallel with the opposite wall, which I felt would be worse.